# Best practice of token authorization

Tags: reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework

I use django+react. What is the best way to token authorization. In all tutorials local storage is used for this. But as I read it is not save way. As i also read, only http cookies are the best way. But there is no any tutorial how to to that?
Is http only cookies the best way to store authentication token.
I use this:

```
class TokenCreateView(TokenCreateView):
    def _action(self, serializer):
        token = utils.login_user(self.request, serializer.user)
        token_serializer_class = settings.SERIALIZERS.token
        response = Response()
        data = token_serializer_class(token).data
        response.set_cookie(
            key='access_token',
            value=data['auth_token'],
            secure=False,
            httponly=True,
            samesite='Lax'
        )
        response.data = {"Success": "Login successfully", "data": data}
        return response
```

But I don't know is that right. Because I didn't find any information and made is as I imaged.

Answer (score 1):

I would use some package instead of creating a custom class for it:
[dj-rest-auth](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
This can work with http-cookies as well.